# Database Replication for a Database that is its own Schemas Database (Replication Guide)

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

The *Database Replication Guide,* chapter "Understanding Database Replication," section "Master and Replica Database Index Settings" states the following:

> You cannot replicate a Master database that acts as its own schema database.
>   When replicating a Master schema database, create a second empty schema database for the Replica schema database on the Replica cluster.

[http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/database-replication/dbrep_intro#id_27654]

Questions:

1. A quick experiment (1. set up two clusters; 2. pair them; 3. set up a database that points to itself for schemas; 4. enable database replication on that database; 5. insert test documents that use configured element range index; 6. test element range index in both primary and replica cluster) seems to suggest that this does in fact work as expected, seemingly to the contrary of what the *Replication Guide* states.
2. I may be misreading the quoted section. Can someone explain why the *Replication Guide* states that "you cannot replicate a Master database that acts as its own schema database"? What is going on under the hood that constitutes a dependency on the Schemas database? If this is done as described under 1. above, what could possibly go wrong? (famous last words :-})

Thank you,

Markus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database replication conserves bandwidth by sending only the documents themselves, not the indexing information for the documents. The receiving forest regenerates the indexing information before inserting the document, and a readable schemas database is sometimes required to do that. If a schemas database is needed, but not available, replication will fail.

The database is temporarily unavailable for query when it is bulk replicating (e.g. after being disconnected for a while, or after a failover).

So while you may not have experienced a problem in your testing so far, you could easily run into a problem down the road when you start actually working with schemas.

Comment: and on a side note - more related to schemas in ML. If you start developing in xQuery, for instance and then add schemas, you may not notice anything. but once you re-index or re-insert a document, MarkLogic references the schema (as Wayne clearly described).   MarkLogic may be schema agnostic, but once schemas are in place, they are used.   Why does this matter? well, the actual datatypes of XML can change with the new information available (schemas). This can cause a difference in how your code works because the datatypes of some elements may be different than your original code expected.

Comment: Thank you Wayne---I think this is starting to make sense for me. I'm assuming that during the commit phase, MarkLogic may have to decide whether a document can get inserted or updated per a given schema, so a content database lagging behind in bulk replication that also holds its own schemas may be problematic.

If I read you correctly, though, putting your schemas into _any_ database that gets writes at high volume and may be likely to experience bulk replication would be a bad idea, not just a content db pointing to itself specifically for schemas. Correct?

Comment: A high update rate doesn't lead to bulk replication; we stall transactions in the master database if its lag limit is exceeded, and resume once the limit is no longer exceeded.